# Eclipse doesn't resolve forward references of scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, fibonacci

I want to construct Fibonacci sequence using this scala specific expression:

```
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
```

but the eclipse compiler complains regarding forward references:

> Forward reference extends over definition of value fibs

With this issue I can't run main method in eclipse.

How should I resolve that?

**edit**
I've tried to declare it in worksheet, main, method and in REPL. The last one works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a limitation of the worksheet. If you put this in a separate class or method it should work.

[edit]

`fibs` needs to be a field. If it's a local val, it needs the lazy modifier.

This should work:

```
 def foo {
   lazy val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
 }
```

or

```
class C {
  val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }
}
```

Comment: I take it back. It only works if `fibs` is a field, not a local val.